# How to filter signal

Tags: matlab, filter, signals, lowpass-filter

I have a signal of walking, but the peaks are noisy at the top, therefore I can't apply findpeaks function. Could you advise me how to best filter out the noise from the signal and how to implement it to MATLAB? I attached a picture of my noisy signal.

[image: Signal I want to filter]

Comment: try using `findpeaks` with its [name-value pair arguments](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html#namevaluepairarguments),
 like `'MinPeakHeight'`, `'MinPeakProminence'`, `'MinPeakDistance'`, etc.

Comment: Just put a threshold to determine where the pulse starts or ends. After that, you may decide if the middle of so determined pulses could be considered as a peak or not. Of course, this is a very rough estimation of the peak. If not, you may wish to perform some lowpass filtering of the signal, to get more smooth signal. Another way would be to determine the pulse width with the same threshold, and to use a simple max value within so determined pulse.